# What is the difference between running @powershell and powershell (any command with @ at the front)?

Tags: command-line, powershell

Just installed [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) and in their [installation instructions](https://chocolatey.org/) they have
`@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted......`

I tried to run **`@cls`** in my console and **it worked too**.

It's amazing to find something new in this space after so many years in the industry.

**What difference `@` makes?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most recognizable instance of this is probably `@echo off` at the beginning of batch files (since DOS).

`@` turns off console echo of that command.  You see it in `@echo off` all the time because if you don't use it, you'll see the actual command `echo off` in the console display when the batch is run. Which is counter-productive when you're trying to control what's displayed/echoed in your batch script. :)

Having said that, I'm not sure why the Chocolaty website says to use it in that (non-batch) context.

Here's Microsoft's TechNet article on [Echo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490897.aspx), which explains the `@`:

> If you want to turn echo off and you do not want to echo the echo command, type an at sign (@) before the command as follows:
>
> @echo off

Turns out someone asked about this a year ago on StackOverflow as well:

- [What is the at sign (@) in a batch file and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074863/what-is-the-at-sign-in-a-batch-file-and-what-does-it-do)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the StackOverflow and Microsoft article, much appreciated. I thought SuperUser is more appropriate site to ask this type of questions. I'm certainly not surprised that this was asked before.