# Using `runas.exe` doesn't seem to work as PowerShell sudo

Tags: windows-7, windows, runas

I am trying to use `runas` in a PowerShell function to serve as a poor man's `sudo`, but `runas` doesn't seem to actually give me admin access. For example, I get an access denied when running:

```
runas /user:admin "cmd /K mkdir C:\Windows\System32\mydirectory"
```

Also, if I open vim and try to write a file to System32, it gives me an error  when I save:

```
runas /user:admin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe C:\Windows\System32\mynewtextfile.txt"
```

I don't think it's a credentials issue, because I can do non-admin tasks like write files to the desktop, and my password seem to work ok. I checked in the "Computer Management" tool in the Administrative Tools, and "admin" is in the "Administrators" group. What am I missing? I am on Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: Here runas is not a powershell function. If in powershell, try `> @powershell saps -credential yourdomain\admin cmd '/K mkdir C:\Windows\System32\mydirectory' -verb runas`.

Comment: Thanks, `Start-Process`/`saps` is what I ended up using. What does the `@powershell` syntax do?

Comment: Nevermind, [I found it](https://superuser.com/questions/864901/what-is-the-difference-between-running-powershell-and-powershell-any-command-w).

Answer (score 0):

I found the following info in the `get-help -full start-process` documentation:

> # Starts a PowerShell process with "Run as Administrator" permissions.
>
> PS C:>start-process powershell.exe -verb runas

The best I can tell, `runas.exe` can change your user but will not elevate your permissions. However, based on the above quote, powershell's `Start-Process` process *can* be used to do this, so I ended up doing the following in my `sudo` function, which seems to be working well enough:

```
$MY_PROFILE_TMP="$Env:TMP\my_profile_tmp";
Function Init-TMP() {
   #Make sure my personal tmp directory exists
   if (!(Test-Path $MY_PROFILE_TMP)) {
      mkdir $MY_PROFILE_TMP | Out-Null
   }
}

Function As-Admin() {
   Init-TMP

   #Create unique temp filenames to capture stderr and stdout
   $GUID=New-Guid
   $ADMIN_OUT="$MY_PROFILE_TMP\$($GUID)_OUT.txt"
   $ADMIN_ERR="$MY_PROFILE_TMP\$($GUID)_ERR.txt"

   #Remove temp files if for some anomoly or error they already exist
   rm -ErrorAction Ignore $ADMIN_OUT
   rm -ErrorAction Ignore $ADMIN_ERR

   #Start powershell with elevated permissions and write to the tmp out and error files
   #Without the &{}, invalid commands like `sudo dinosaur` don't get
   #captured to the error file
   Start-Process powershell "& { $args } 2>$ADMIN_ERR > $ADMIN_OUT" -Verb runas -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden

   #Write to the current console the out and error results from the elevated process
   #TODO ideally, we'd read from these as a stream  so the order would be correct...
   cat $ADMIN_ERR -Delimiter None | Write-Error
   cat $ADMIN_OUT

   #Remove the temp files
   rm -ErrorAction Ignore $ADMIN_OUT
   rm -ErrorAction Ignore $ADMIN_ERR
}

#Make an alias "sudo"
New-Alias -Name sudo -Value As-Admin
```

Comment: How are we supposed to use this lengthy script? And why "Start-Process powershell"? From the question, it is other commands that are supposed to start, not PowerShell.

Comment: It is used semi-similarly to *nix `sudo`: `sudo "mkdir C:\Windows\System32\followthewhiterabbit"`. Start-Process is used because, as chingNotCHing mentioned, it's `-Verb runas` option gives you elevated permissions that the exe `runas` does not. My goal is to run powershell commands (including functions),  so I use Start-Process to start an elevated powershell to run my commands. The script is long because originally when using `runas` I couldn't find a better way to capture the output other than writing to a tmp file. With `Start-Process` perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Following my investigation in Windows 10, the following commands **WORK**:

**Elevation:**

```
saps -Verb RunAs "cmd" -Arg "/K mkdir C:\Windows\System32\mydirectory"
```

**Switching users:**

```
saps -Verb RunAsUser "cmd" -Arg "/K mkdir C:\Windows\System32\mydirectory"
```

The following commands **DO NOT WORK**:

- `runas /user:admin "cmd /K mkdir C:\Windows\System32\mydirectory"` – This does not result in elevation of privileges
- `saps -Credential admin "cmd" -Arg "/K mkdir C:\Windows\System32\mydirectory"` – This does not result in elevation of privileges
- `New-Item -Credential admin "C:\Windows\System32\mydirectory"` – The FileSystem provider does not support alternative credentials except for New-PSDrive cmdlet.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have UAC on? If so, are you running the PowerShell script from an elevated prompt?

The runas command is subject to the UAC restrictions of its parent command window. If you didn't invoke the runas command from an elevated prompt, the user won't have elevated credentials even if it's an administrative account.

Unfortunately, this is just how UAC works. The only difference is that a CLI application (such as runas) cannot prompt for elevation when it needs to the way a GUI program can. There is no Windows equivalent to the sudo command in *NIX operating systems.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. It is what we already know from the question.

Comment: Yes, UAC is on. .No, I am not running from an elevated prompt.